# causal rectangular signal fourier transform example question

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a discrete time fourier transform example for rectangular function. I understand most of the steps but I don't get how $e^{-j5\omega}$ came from when it tries to change the summation limit terms back to -5 to 5 in the second last step. I know this is a very basic question but I couldn't find out why on my own.

[image]

Comment: Set $n=(k+5)$ in the expression from step 2, and you will easily get to the expression in step 3, except with $k$ as the index.

Answer (score 1):

This is using the time shift property of the fourier transform. A shift in the time domain by $a$ corresponds to a phase shift in the frequency domain.

$$f(x-a)\xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}e^{-ja\Omega}F(f) $$

In this case, it helps to transform the summands to a well known basic form with an easy solution.